# Как удалить конкретный commit на GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-commit, commit

Допустим в проекте на GitHub у меня 4 коммита, я хочу удалить второй. Как это сделать?

Не удалиться ли из-за этого часть кода (я хочу просто сделать так, чтобы второй коммит не отображался в списке коммитов)?

А также, будут ли какие-то изменения в процессе, если второй коммит я запушил с другого аккаунта.

Comment: Что вы хотите, чтоб случилось с изменениями, которые были сделаны в том комите?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, мне бы хотелось удалить коммит из истории коммитов, а изменения, которые этот коммит внёс, оставить

Comment: Если вы хотите оставить изменения, значит они должны попасть в какой-то другой коммит. https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо, оформите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять